# Replacing .addStream() for video WebRTC

Tags: javascript, streaming, video-streaming, webrtc

Since `RTCPeerConnection.addStream()` is deprecated, how does one now add a media stream such as video to a peerConnection?

Here is the video stream capture function that I am currently using. I wanted to see if I am getting a media stream back from my camera and indeed I am. But then how do I add the stream to a peer connection?

```
var constraints = {
  audio: false,
  video: true
};

function successCallback(stream) {
  window.stream = stream; // stream available to console
  if (window.URL) {
    document.getElementById('localVid').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('localVid').src = stream;
  }
    peerConn.addStream(s); //deprecated so onaddstream is not fired
}

function errorCallback(error) {
  console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
}
```

I have successfully set up a signaling system for data channels and now I am moving on to streaming, however the limited resources are frustrating and I need some help.

Comment: In the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/addStream) they say you should switch to `addTrack()` method and instead of the `onaddstream` event use `ontrack` event. Have you tried it?

Comment: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/ is a collection of samples that are continously updated and reviewed by people working for both Google and Mozilla. If you still use URL.createURLObject (which is no longer what the specification recommends) you should take a look at the alternatives shown there.

Comment: "Deprecated" doesn't mean it wont work today, you'll just see a friendly warning in the web console of Firefox. Did you try it?

Answer (score 3):

Mozilla decided to deprecate addStream without Chrome implementing the new alternative addTrack yet. addStream is still supported and I doubt it is going to be removed while it remains the one and only method available in Chrome.

Note that onaddstream is fired if a remote stream to a peerconnection, not if a local stream is added.

Comment: Technically, [the spec](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#rtcpeerconnection-interface-extensions) deprecated `addStream`. Mozilla is just trying to keep up with the spec.

Comment: I am developing in chrome. Does this mean that addTrack is not supported yet and I will still have to use aaddStream?

Comment: @PjRigor Yes. Until Chrome fixes it, `addStream` remains the API with most support across browsers. Alternatively, you can try to detect support with `let pc = new RTCPeerConnection(config); if ("addTrack" in pc) { /* use addTrack */ }`